# Node.js with socket.io, capturing form data to display on page

Tags: node.js, forms, post, socket.io

What I am trying to do is basic, but cant get my data back to the page. I want to capture some usewr information in a form before I direct them to a chat screen, once directed to the chat screen I will use form data to append their name and question(from the form) to the chat window.

**I have edited the original post, if I change the line return data in index.js to:***

```
io.emit('user capture', data)
```

***...and comment out the display none on the chat window.**

**I get the data posted to the chat window, now I just need to be able to hide the chat window... Any ideas?**

Below is my index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <style>
      * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
      body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
      form[name="chat"] { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
      form[name="chat"] input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: .5%; }
      form[name="chat"] button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
      #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
      #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
      /*.chat { display: none; }*/
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="pages">
      <div class="user_capture">
        <form name="user_capture" enctype='application/json'>
          <button>Close</button><br/><br/>
          <label for="username">Your Name: *</label><br/>
          <input id="username" type="text" value="" name="username" autocomplete="off" required="required" /><br/>
          <label for="email">Email: *</label><br/>
          <input id="email" value="" name="email_address" autocomplete="off" /><br/>
          <label for="phone">Phone:</label><br/>
          <input id="phone" value="" name="phone" autocomplete="off" /><br/>
          <label for="question">Question: </label><br/>
          <textarea id="question" name="question">
          </textarea required="required"><br/><br/>
          <button>Chat</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="chat">
        <ul id="messages"></ul>
        <form name="chat">
          <input id="message" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script>
      var socket = io();
      $('form[name="user_capture"]').submit(function(){
        var data = {
          username:$('[name="username"]').val(),
          question:$('[name="question"]').val()
        }
        socket.emit('user capture', data);
        //return false;
      });

      socket.on('user capture', function(data){
        $('form[name="user_capture"]').hide();
        $('form[name="chat"]').show();
        // $('#messages').append(data.username +' says: '+ data.question);
      });


      $('form[name="chat"]').submit(function(){
        socket.emit('chat message', $('#message').val());
        $('#message').val('');
        return false;
      });

      socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Below is my index.js:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

var status = 'Disconnected';

app.get('', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    var status = 'Connected';
    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        io.emit('chat message', msg);
        io.emit('status', status);
    });
    socket.on('user capture', function(data){
        io.emit('user capture', data);
    });
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

So you guys were right the form was submitting refreshing the page and causing loss of data I also decided to not use a form at all.. Just inputs and  tags as I am not using PHP so no need for POST. Below is my working code:

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <style>
      * { box-sizing: border-box; }
      body { margin: 0; padding: 0; font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
      [data-close] { float: right; }
      [data-status] { width: 100%; }
      .chat { display: none; }
      .chat .send-area { background: #000; padding: 15px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
      .chat .send-arae input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: .5%; }
      .chat [data-send] { float: right; text-align: center;width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
      .chat .send-area #message { width: 90%; padding: 9px; }
      #messages { width: 70%;float: left; list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
      #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
      [data-online] { float: right; background: #d9d9d9; width: 30%; }
      .clr { clear: both; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="pages">
      <a href="#" data-close>Close</a>
      <div class="user_capture">
          <label for="username">Your Name: *</label><br/>
          <input id="username" type="text" value="" name="username" /><br/>
          <label for="email">Email: *</label><br/>
          <input id="email" value="" name="email_address" /><br/>
          <label for="phone">Phone:</label><br/>
          <input id="phone" value="" name="phone" /><br/>
          <label for="question">Question: </label><br/>
          <textarea id="question" name="question">
          </textarea><br/><br/>
          <a href="#" data-user-capture>Chat</a>
      </div>
      <div class="chat">
        <div data-status></div>
        <ul id="messages"></ul>
        <ul data-online>
        </ul>
        <div class="clr"></div>
          <div class="send-area">
            <input id="message" autocomplete="off" /><a href="" data-send>Send</a>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){

        var socket = io.connect();
        var $close = $('[data-close]');

        $close.unbind().bind('click', function(){
          if(window.confirm("Are you sure?")) {
            location.reload();
          }
        });

        //CAPTURE
        $('[data-user-capture]').unbind().bind('click', function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          //hide form show chat window
          $('.user_capture').hide();
          $('.chat').show();

          var data = {
            username:$('[name="username"]').val(),
            question:$('[name="question"]').val(),
          }
          socket.emit('user capture', data);
        });
        socket.on('user capture', function(data){
          $('#messages').append('<li><strong>'+data.username +' says: </strong>'+data.question+'<li>');
          console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
          $('[data-status]').append('<strong>Status: </strong>'+data.status);
          //$('[data-online]').each(data.online_users).append('<li>'+online+'</li>')
        });

        //SEND MESSAGE
        $('[data-send]').unbind().bind('click', function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          if(!$('#message').val()){
            $('#message').focus();
            $('#message').attr('placeholder', 'Please enter a message...');
          } else {
            socket.emit('send', $('#message').val());
            $('#message').val('');
            // return false;
          }
        });

        socket.on('send', function(data){
          $('#messages').append('<li><strong>'+data.username +' says: </strong>'+data.msg+'<li>');
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(http);
var username;
var online_users = [];
var status = 'Disconnected';

app.get('', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('user capture', function(data){
    socket.username = data.username;
    data.online_users.push(socket.username);
    data.status = 'Connected';
    io.emit('user capture', data);
    console.log(data);
  });
    socket.on('send', function(msg){
    sendData = {
      msg:msg,
      username:socket.username
    };
    io.sockets.emit('send', sendData);
  });
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use following code

```
 $('form[name="user_capture"]').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = {
          username:$('[name="username"]').val(),
          question:$('[name="question"]').val()
        }
```

Comment: Changing submit to click didn't change anything, also the function that posts messages to the chat area is working and that uses submit also. P.S I am hiding the form and displaying chat after submit of the user_capture form... This is really baffling me!